# prevent clicks on entire page if not trusted

Tags: javascript

Building a web game in my spare time and people have been using auto clickers to do things I don't intend.

This is an extremely dumbed down example:

```js
button1.onclick = handleButton1Click
button2.onclick = handleButton2Click
```

What I want to to is prevent untrusted clicks and really HOPED this method wouldve worked:

```js
button1.onclick = handleButton1Click
button2.onclick = handleButton2Click

window.onclick = e => {
  if (!e.isTrusted) {
    e.stopPropagation()
    return false
  }
}
```

But this doesn't do what I'm looking for, for what I'm assuming is because they're separate events.

Is there something I can do besides doing the `isTrusted` check on every click event?

Comment: Well you can't really do that in a bullet proof way, they will figure out how to disable your onclick handler, autoclickers will have isTrusted to true

Comment: Thats fine with me tbh. The people who actually know how to code will easily find a way around it, however, im more so targeting the vast majority of my players who just use plugins to handle their autoclicking etc.

Comment: Well the issue is that external autoclickers will simulate a real mouse click, and isTrusted will be true, you will need a way on the server to identify cheaters by metrics, like how many clicks, how many ms between clicks... If they click every 150ms precisely that's easy to identify, if the click is randomized that's way harder

Comment: That actually was my previous method. Logging the 3 most recent clicks and checking the delay in between. However, it doesnt solve the problem im currently facing. Which is I need a way to cancel all clicks if the click isnt a valid click without adding that if statement everywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow the approach you had, but instead of listening globally you can wrap your calls so you can do the check on the actual click.

```js
const button1 = document.querySelector('#button1');
const button2 = document.querySelector('#button2');

const handleButton1Click = (evt) => {
  console.log("1", evt.target);
  evt.currentTarget.classList.toggle('active');
}

const handleButton2Click = (evt) => {
  console.log("2", evt.target);
  evt.currentTarget.classList.toggle('active');
}

const clean = (fnc) =>
  (e) => {
    if (!e.isTrusted) {
      console.log('blocked');
      e.stopPropagation()
      return false
    }
    return fnc(e);
  }


button1.onclick = clean(handleButton1Click);
button2.onclick = clean(handleButton2Click);


button1.click();
button1.click();
button2.click()
```

```css
.active {
  color: yellow;
  background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<button id='button1'>button1</button>
<button id='button2'>button2</button>
```

You can throttle the calls here too so a user can not click it more than once every X milliseconds.